# Why does positive cloud-to-ground lightning have no branches?

Tags: electricity, lightning

I have been learning about the physics of lightning lately. Several sources (for example, the book *Lightning: Physics and Effects* by Vladimir A. Rakov and Martin A. Uman) state that positive cloud-to-ground lightning generally appears as a single bright stroke without branches. I have been trying to understand the reason why positive lightning lacks branches but haven't been able to find a source that explains this. Could someone please explain why there are usually no branches in positive cloud-to-ground lightning?